# where can I get math book reviews?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, online-resources, book-recommendation

The only two freely available choices are maa.org and zbmath.org ,where can get other mathematical book reviews?
any one?

Comment: **Some** book reviews on Amazon are decent.

Comment: The Gazette of the Australian Math Society, http://www.austms.org.au/gazette

Comment: Notices of the American Mathematical Society (freely available) has book reviews. Also, Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society has a lot of book reviews (freely available back to the 1890s).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, the most recent issue of the Australian Mathematical Society Gazette (Volume 41, Number 3, 2014) has reviews of the books,

1. Borwein and Vanderwerff, *Convex Functions*,
2. Adler, *Wizards, Aliens and Starships*,
3. Lang, *Origami Design Secrets*,
4. Pewsey, Neuhäuser, Ruxton, *Circular Statistics in R*, and
5. Singh, *Linear Algebra: Step By Step*.